# group_concat doesn't work with count

Tags: mysql, count, group-concat

I use the

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `a`.`IDperson` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `person`,
COUNT(`a`.`IDjobs`) AS `total`
FROM
`a`
GROUP BY `a`.`ID_person`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

and what I need is to get back results like

```
person        total
 2342           98
 1342           75
 3844           70
 1705           62
 3309           53
 5918, 1328     52
 1503, 1890     46
21004, 6536     45
```

but it doesn't work
what it gets back is like GROUP_CONCT to not working

```
    person        total
     2342           98
     1342           75
     3844           70
     1705           62
     3309           53
     5918           52
     1328           52
     1503           46
     1890           46
    21004           45
     6536           45
```

Comment: do you get any errors??

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) works perfectly. Since you `GROUP BY a.ID_person`, each group contains only one value of `a.ID_person`, hence the results you get. You probably want to `GROUP BY` other column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you need  concat grouing by  the  number of count so  you should

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.IDperson SEPARATOR ', ') AS person,  t.total
from (
      select DISTINCT a.IDperson as IDPerson, COUNT(a.IDjobs) AS `total`
      FROM a
      GROUP BY a.ID_person ) t 
group by t.total
ORDER BY t.total DESC
```

Comment: it reponces with ERROR 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you want:

```
SELECT numjobs, GROUP_CONAT(idperson SEPARATOR ', ' ORDER BY idperson) as persons
FROM (SELECT idperson, COUNT(*) as numjobs
      FROM a
      GROUP BY idperson
     ) ap
GROUP BY numjobs
ORDER BY numjobs DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) works perfectly. Since you `` GROUP BY `a`.`ID_person` ``, each group contains only one value of `` `a`.`ID_person` ``, hence the results you get. You probably want to `` `GROUP BY `a`.`IDjobs` ``:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `a`.`IDperson` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `person`,
    COUNT(`a`.`IDjobs`) AS `total`
FROM
   `a`
GROUP BY `a`.`IDjobs`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

Comment: no it doesn't work. It returns unmatched data like
person                                                    
11837, 16140, 17081, 17084, 17085, 17087, 20032, 27849, 30414, 31470, 31891 

total 11

Comment: You didn't describe in the question how the table looks like, what is the relationship between the `IDjobs` and `IDperson` fields and what are the aggregation rules. Given the question is not well defined, any answer works, as long as it produces aggregate values in the `person` column. If you need an answer that works to your actual needs then describe the needs better.